# Use a file to extract specified rows from another file

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

input1:

```
1    s1
100  s100
90   s90
```

input2:

```
a    1
b    3
c    7
d    100
e    101
f    90
```

Output:

```
a    1
d    100
f    90
```

I know `join` can do this, but it needs to (1) sort these common fields (2) after join, I need to remove the second column from input1. Does anyone have better solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } $2 in a' file1 file2
```

Results:

```
a    1
d    100
f    90
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|(\S+).*|/\\<\1$/p|' input1 | sed -nf - input2
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, grep might do:

```
grep -wFf <(cut -d' ' -f1 input1) input2
```

Output:

```
a    1
d    100
f    90
```

Note that grep is not column-aware and will happily match where it can.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know awk is better soluiton for this,but since its already provided :below is the perl solution.

```
> perl -F -lane '$H{$F[0]}=$F[1];END{%T=reverse(%H);foreach (values %H){if(exists($H{$_})){print $T{$_}." ".$_;}}}' file1 file2
a 1
d 100
f 90
```