# AWK: How to extract rows from one file based on rows of another file?

Tags: awk

Here is my file a.txt:

```
a|hello
b|it
c|is
d|such
e|a
f|nice
g|day
```

And I have file b.txt:

```
b
d
e
g
```

How do I extract rows in file a.txt based on the rows of b.txt? I know I can do it by making a dictionary but is there a easy way for doing so using awk?

Comment: There are numerous similar questions with answers here on SO.  This is a duplicate, therefore.

Comment: You might find [Use a file to extract specified rows from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834218/) simpler than the duplicate I chose, though it is a couple of years more recent.  Similarly with [Extract rows and substrings from one file conditional on information of another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836300/).  I have no doubt there are other exemplars.  I used SO search term '`[awk] extract rows`' and sorted by votes.

Comment: you do not need awk, just use join